# CoreGraphics performance with gradients

Tags: ios, ipad, core-animation, core-graphics

I have multiple shapes on the screen which are moving.
Each shape can change based on its location and they are filled with gradient using CoreGraphics.

The performance of this is very bad - ~9fps on iPad3.

Any tips for speeding this up? Would it help to have a pre-rendered bitmap and reshape this instead?

I am recalculating the shape (triangle) and redrawing the on every movement:

```
- (void) drawGradientShapeInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGFloat start_x = self.frame.size.width / 2.0;
    CGFloat start_y = self.frame.size.height;

    CGFloat end_x = radius_ * cos(angleInRad_) + start_x;
    CGFloat end_y = MAX(radius_ * sin(angleInRad_) + start_y, self.bounds.size.height - constrainedHeight_);

    // Create Lines
    CGPoint startPt = CGPointMake(start_x, start_y);

    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, self.center.x, self.center.y);
    CGPoint addLines[] =
    {
        startPt,
        CGPointMake(end_x, end_y),
        CGPointMake(end_x, start_y),
        startPt
    };

    CGContextAddLines(context, addLines, sizeof(addLines)/sizeof(addLines[0]));

    // Setup Gradient
    CGColorSpaceRef rgb = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    NSArray *colors = nil;
    if(start_x > end_x)
    {
        colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                  (id)[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0].CGColor,
                  (id)[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.3f].CGColor,
                  nil];
    }
    else
    {
        colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                  (id)[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.3f].CGColor,
                  (id)[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0].CGColor,
                  nil];
    }

    CGColorSpaceRef space = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(space, (__bridge CFArrayRef)colors, NULL);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(space);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(rgb);

    CGPoint startGradientPt = CGPointMake((start_x < end_x) ? start_x : end_x, 0);
    CGPoint endGradientPt   = CGPointMake((start_x > end_x) ? start_x : end_x, 0);

    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGContextClip(context);
    CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context,
                                gradient,
                                startGradientPt,
                                endGradientPt,
                                0);
    CGGradientRelease(gradient);
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
}
```

Comment: How are you drawing the shapes? How are you moving them? Etc. etc. (We need more details)

Comment: Updated - will ad more later.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up creating PNGs instead which can be shrunk and shaped.
Frame rate immediately jumped to 40fps - problem solved.

Comment: How do you stretch a gradient without it looking terrible?

Comment: Made a semi-transparent 500x500 gradient triangle in photoshop - in all shapes the quality is close to that drawn in CG on retina screen. On non-retina the edges are a touch 'hard'

Comment: OK, so you're shrinking it normally, rather than stretching it. Makes sense.